# Copying files from parent and subfolders to a destination folder

Tags: unix

I have a Parent Folder(with some files), under which I have set of sub-folders with files.
At first, need to copy files from parent folder to a Destination Folder. 
After that based on oldest creation timestamp of sub-folder, files need to copied to the Destination folder recursively till the latest folder in a loop.
If any files are with same name, then new file should replace the old file in the destination folder.

I was able to copy files from Parent folder to destination folder. But I am not able to proceed further on copying the files, looping through the sub-folders based on timestamp from oldest to new sub-folder.

Today=$(date +%Y%m%d -d "today")
mkdir $Today
Yesterday=$(date +%Y%m%d -d "yesterday")
$ find $Yesterday -maxdepth 1 -exec \cp {} $Today \;

Copy Parent files first, then copying files from oldest sub-folder to new sub-folder based on timestamp. Replace with new file if already old file exists in the destination folder. Request your help on this!!

Input:
ParentFolder : File_1.txt, File_2.txt, File_3.txt
subfolder1(old subfolder) : Folder1_1.txt, Folder1_2.txt, File_1.txt
subfolder2(new subfolder) : Folder2_1.txt, Folder2_2.txt, File_3.txt

Output:
DestinationFolder : File_1.txt(from subfolder1), File_2.txt, File_3.txt(from subfolder2), Folder1_1.txt, Folder1_2.txt, Folder2_1.txt, Folder2_2.txt

Comment: You can copy recursively using -a or -R flag. Check [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44967/difference-between-cp-r-and-cp-a) for details

Comment: Below code worked, Thank you..                                                    
Today=$(date +%Y%m%d -d "today")
mkdir $Today
Yesterday=$(date +%Y%m%d -d "yesterday")
find $Yesterday/*/*.txt -type f -print0 | xargs -0 ls -tr | while read file
do
    cp "$file" $Today/${file##*/};
done